# Горячее редактирование формулы

Tags: php

Всем доброго времени суток!

На странице есть несколько таблиц и формула.
Значение из всех таблиц берутся,подставляются в формулу и высчитываются значения для результирующей таблицы.

Проблема состоит в том, что иногда необходимо формулу менять(скобки,арифметические знаки). 
И каждый раз ручками  переписывать -  не вариант. Вот я и думаю:

1. Как хранить такую формулу? (в БД , в файле)
2. Как её парсить?

Тонкость в том, что формула имеет следующий(примерный) вид:

> 3*(С+)*11 + 4*(В) - 7*(А+) + 1*(С)  , где С!=С+

Как видно, переменная С+ при парсинге может распознаться как С и знак "+".

есть у кого какие идеи?

Answer (score 1):

Если C+3 должно парсится однозначно как C+ 3, а не C + 3, то перед парсингом формулы заменяем все C+ на, скажем, D(по ситуации, можно на любой другой символ) и формула получается такая:

```
3(D)11 + 4(В) - 7(E) + 1*(С)
```

, а это - уже школьная задачка по программированию: написать калькулятор. =)